# Есть ли основания использовать подобный подход?

Tags: c#, lambda

Заинтересовался конструкцией из JavaScript:

```
(function(){ /* code */ })();
```

решил попробовать реализовать подобное на C#:

```
public Func<T,U> λ<T,U>(Func<T,U> f)
{
    return f;
}
```

Работать можно примерно следующим образом:

```
var i = λ((int x) => x*x + 2*x + 3)(5);// 38

var j = λ((string x) => x.Split(' '))("a bc def");// ["a", "bc", "def"]
```

хотелось бы услышать **критику** и/или идеи для развития подобной идеи.

**UPD:** теперь, когда функция называется **λ** (u03bb), а не  _  очень похоже на полноценное лямбда-выражения, хоть и менее практично, осталось избавится от типа формального параметра, у кого-нить есть идеи?

---

**UPD2:** ещё немного кодобреда:

исходя из определения логических операторов в λ-исчеслениях

```
true = λx. λy. x
false = λx. λy. y
not = λt. t false true
```

на С# получаем следующие

```
public Func<T,T> True<T>(T x)
{
    return λ((T y)=>x);
}

public Func<T,T> False<T>(T x)
{
    return λ((T y)=>y);
}

public Func<T,Func<T,T>> Not<T>(Func<Func<T, Func<T, T>>, Func<Func<T,  Func<T, T>>, Func<T, Func<T, T>>>> t)
{
    return t(False)(True);
}
```

способ использования(**ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО** в образовательных целях)

```
var true1 = λ((int x)=>λ((int y)=>x))(12)(21);// True 12

var true2 = True(12)(21);// 12

var false1 = False(12)(21);// 21

var false2 = Not<int>(True)(12)(21);// 21
```

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем нужна функция _, которая возвращает ровно то, что ей передают?

Comment: чтобы вызвать анонимную функцию сразу после ей объявления

Comment: В javascript безыменные функции обычно используются для того, чтобы создать замыкание

Comment: @aachurin, не безымянные, а анонимные)

Comment: Как безымянные (они же анонимные, вопрос перевода) функции могут иметь имя, хотя бы по логике? См. хотя бы здесь http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_Functions

Comment: Почитай полезно будет [Функциональное программирование][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Есть, например, книга T.Petricec, J.Skeet Functional Programming in Real World. With examples in F# and C#

Comment: Вообще-то безымянные функции имени по определению не имеют, но могут быть значением именованной переменной. А то получается, как в "ДМБ" про суслика: "А он есть"

Comment: да, знаю я про всё это, и про книгу тоже - начинал читать, я имею ввиду именно такой подход, т.к. такой способ вызова функций сразу же после объявления 

    var k = new Func<int, string>(x=>x.ToString())(123)//"123"

тоже подходит, я немного упростил вычисления типов, и если по перегружуть функцию _, то можно будет работать с произвольным кол-вом параметров

Интересно, стоит ли игра свеч?

Comment: Хотя-бы так:

    (
    function my_fn(){
      my_fn();
    }
    )();

Comment: и словить StackOverflow из-за бесконечной рекурсии?

Comment: Это только пример) что анонимная фукнция - имеет имя)

Comment: Объявление функции __function declaration__ - всегда должно иметь имя:

    function foo(){}

Функциональное выражение __function expression__. Имя не обязательно, в силу того, что это выражение 
    
    var foo = function(){}

хотя никто не запрещает указать и тогда мы получаем __named function expression__, где bar - это имя функции. При этом имя bar будет доступно __только в скопе__ самой функции

    var foo = function bar(){}

Тоже самое и со скобками - __named function expression__. Так как скобки - это оператор группировки, а он может содержать только выражение

    (function bar(){})

Answer (score 3):

Вы просто играетесь с синтаксическим сахаром, который лежит за известным понятием *лямбда-функции.*

Существует общеизвестная абстракция `Func<T, U>`, которая являет собой некоторый функциональный объект и может облагаться каким-либо контрактом в ходе выполнения. При этом выгода `λ-подобной` записи достаточно сомнительна, поскольку разработчики уже привыкли к использованию `Func`:

```
var t1 = new Func<string, int>(s => s.Length)("X");
var t2 = λ(s => s.Length)("X");
```

Любая современная IDE после ввода `var t = s => s.Length` автоматически предложит вам преобразовать лямбда-выражение в функциональный объект.

---

**Короче, если подытожить, то вы просто переименовали `new Func<?>` в `λ`.** С таким же успехом, например, можно переименовать `Dictionary` в `D`. Это, конечно, здорово, но не слишком полезно.

Comment: да, я это описывал в комментариях, просто была идея в дальнейшем написать таким образом некий лямбда-интерпретатор(понимаю, что C# не самый лучший претендент на это дело), что-то вроди:

    true =  λx. λy. x
    false = λx. λy. y
    not = λt. t false true
    ...

кстате, компилятор требует явного указания типа формальных параметров, как этого можно избежать? может есть какой-то хитрый способ?

Answer (score 2):

Нижеизложенное в основном мое личное мнение.

Смысла функционального исчисления не в том, что функции анонимные или имеют какую то особенную нотацию, а в том, что там нет переменных и состояний.

Из-за этого в нем приходится МУЧАТЬСЯ, из-за этого там придумали нотацию с т.н. лямбда-выражениями.

Все это потом выполняется на машинах Тьюринга, приспособленных для императивных языков, в которых есть переменные и состояния.

В С# и другие языки добавили нотацию, но не добавили ограничения на отсутствие состояний. Можно ведь в таких функциях переменные использовать и менять.

То есть форма без сути. Мучения без выгоды.

Почему это стали делать? Похоже, что дело в образовании. В ВУЗах США массово внедрили Java (не слушая профессоров). Несчастные преподаватели, понимающие, что обучение на этом языке навсегда испортит студентам мышление и закроет возможность стать программистом начали искать выход в замене его на функциональные языки. Например, тот самый Дейкстра, который дожил до 2002 года, преподавал в Техасе и увидел наяву воплощение всех своих худших кошмаров. Ну а дальше как обычно - чему в институте научили, то и тиражируют. Теперь эти псевдолямбда выражения и псевдофункциональное программирование суют везде. Причем форму, а не содержание.