# Что такое лямбда-выражения?

Tags: функции, lambda

Что это, зачем используется? Примеры...

Comment: Тут так практически про всё можно написать

Comment: @niki-timofe, это слабое оправдание. Если вы не приложите усилий, чтобы задать хороший вопрос, то не можете ожидать, что мы приложим усилия, чтобы дать хороший ответ. Таким образом вам придется удовлетвориться копипастой из ссылки выше, что несколько глупо для программиста, ибо подразумевает выполнение машинной работы вручную.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Лямбда-функции - это функции, у которой фактически нет имени. Таким образом математики упростили до невозможности формат записи функции, а вообще лямбда-исчислениями пытались формализовать вычисления

```
λx.x
```

`λ` — означает, что это лямбда-функция. Всё что после неё - список аргументов, в идеале абсолютно любого типа, в том числе может быть и другая лямбда-функция. После точки идёт "тело функции", а уже потом, собственно, идёт аргумент, который будет передан. Т.о.

```
λx.x+2 2 // вернёт 4
```

Пример посложнее:

```
λx.x 2 λy.y+1 // результат 3
```

Здесь в качестве параметра x выступает другая лямбда-функция `λy.y + 1`, в которую передаётся параметр 2. То есть любая лямбда функция является функцией высшего порядка, может принимать в качестве аргумента другую функцию и возвращать функцию:

```
λx.λy.y+x+3 2 // вернёт λy.y+5, т.к. x был равен двум.

λx.λy.y+x+3 2 3 // вернёт 8. Фактически это каррирование: сначала функция принимает аргумент 2 и возвращает функцию, которая принимает ещё один аргумент и возвращает результат.
```

Если интересно, я когда-то писал [аналогичные вещи на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/63865/%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Теперь давайте посмотрим, как же все наши примеры будут выглядеть на C#. Здесь в качестве лямбда-функции я использую [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx), где T - тип аргумента, а U - тип возвращаемого значения:

```
1) Func<int, int> func = x=>x;
2) var result = new Func<int,int>(x=>x+2)(2);
3) var result = new Func<Func<int,int>, int>(x=>x(2))(new Func<int,int>(y=>y+1));
4) var result = new Func<int, Func<int, int>>(x=>y=>y+x+3)(2);
5) var result = new Func<int, Func<int, int>>(x=>y=>y+x+3)(2)(3);
```

Сложность составляет только явное указание типа аргументов и возвращаемого значения.

Comment: `λx.λy.y+x+3 2` называется по-ненашему currying (карринг, частичное применение) в честь Хаскела Карри. (см. языки программирования haskell и curry)

Comment: это вы к чему? к тому же карринг и частичное применение - разные вещи

Comment: Тогда хотелось бы видеть официальный перевод термина currying. (Карринг вроде в русском языке пока не утвердился)

Comment: я знаю, что википедия не самый достоверный источник, но всё же - [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Каррирование](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Каррирование)

Comment: Однако хотелось бы узнать мнение математика.

Comment: @Spectre на хабре недавно была [статья про различия между каррингом и частичным применением](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143465/)

Comment: @Андрей. Для того, чтобы понять различия, надо углубляться в C#. Эта канитель, если я правильно понял, возникает, когда для вызова функции используется какой-то специальный синтаксис. Тогда как в случае лямбда-исчисления таких тонкостев не найти по причине их ненужности.

Comment: Соврешенно неправильный ответ, тем более, что в вопросе нет тега Java. А вы начали ложное определение, которым почему то создатели Java внутри своего языка использовать.

Comment: недавно узнал для себя, что значит хороший специалист, это человек который может сложные вещи по своей области, объяснить простыми словами человеку который мало, что в этой области понимает. Два десятка ваших строк стоит больше половины публикаций на эту тему.

Answer (score 11):

lambda - это простыми словами функция которая лежит прямо в переменной, если мы хотим записать функцию в переменную то мы сначала должны описать эту функцию

```
def main(a,b):
   return a+1,b-1

tools = main(3,4)
// 43
print(tools)
```

используя lambda

```
a,b = (3,4) 
tools = lambda a,b: (a+1, b-1)

print(tools)
```

благодаря записи в одну строку её можно удобно вставлять куда-угодно.

Comment: Что касается питона, то там лямда-выражения слабые (если не изменили в python3), не позволяют описывать сложные функции. Аргументация -- в питоне легко создавать локальные функции, и это позволяет не горевать по поводу имён. Лямбда в javascript

     (function (x) {return x+1})(5);
     var f = function (x) {return x*2};

Answer (score 10):

Лямда-выражения -- анонимные функции. Приползло из математики, где использовалась специальная форма записи функций, ликвидирующая неоднозначности функция/значение функции и пр. Благодаря усилиям верстальщиков (не html-, а типографских набощиков) из формы $hat x.x$, оно трансформировалось в $wedge x.x$, ну а далее, уже естественно -- в $lambda x.x$

Т.е. значение лямбда-выражения -- это функция, которая может быть применена к какому-то аргументу/аргументам.

Comment: Ещё бы кто объяснил, как тут формулы записывать... А то что-то пробегало про формат LaTeX.

Comment: Увы, оно тут не работает, только на матх.

Comment: Тогда словами. Изначатьльно x "под шапкой^".x, был переделан в "знак конъюнкции"x.x, а уже потом лямбда x.x

Answer (score 0):

Укажите подробности (язык в частности ). Лямбда выражения - это [анонимные функторы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))( переменные, содержащие целую функцию ).  *Лямбда-выражение допускает замыкание на лексический контекст, в котором это выражение использовано.* В PHP, например, такое выражение создается так:

```
$func = create_function("$a,$b","return $a+$b;");  //  lambda-style функция
echo $func(1,2); //3
```

[**Больше**](http://www.php.su/functions/?create-html)

Comment: Язык C/C#/C++, VB.NET

Comment: Стандарт C++ 11 позволяет это реализовать так:

     [](int x, int y) { return x + y; }

Comment: А зачем тогда `=>` ??

Comment: PHP 5.3+

    $func = function( $a, $b ) {
       return $a + $b;
    };

    echo $func(1,2);

@niki-timofe - так `=>` в C#, если не ошибаюсь, там тупо другой синтаксис =)

Comment: В PHP `create_function` **не** имеет никакого отношения к анонимным функциям и является оберткой для `eval`, которая на каждый вызов создает поименованную функцию с именем «`lambda_N`», где N — натуральное число. Относительно новый синтаксис `$f = function(...) { ... }` уже ведет себя как анонимная функция (например, не передекларируется в цикле), и является объектом типа `Closure`, который ведет себя как функция (но функцией не является, в результате чего работает не везде).

Comment: Вопрос в никуда: Почему об этом нет **ни одного слова на php.net**?..
(я о eval'e)

Я полагаю - это "немножко" важная информация, которая должна быть выделена жирным шрифтом в описании функции (а лучше вообще перед), но нет:

create_function — Create an anonymous (lambda-style) function

Comment: В похапе добавили, потому что *сходите на Кузнецкий, все в лаковых*. Но концовка предсказуемая - получилось как всегда.

Comment: Тому що похапе.

Если что, подтверждение про eval — оно видно [в коде реализации `create_function`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L1785). Собирается строка и кормится `zend_eval_stringl`. Та создает функцию с именем `__lambda_func`, потом функция переименовывается в `\0lambda_`номер (\0 - символ NUL).

Comment: @drdeaman - я знаю что это eval, но меня, мягко говоря, удивляет то, что в документации об этом нет ни слова, по-моему это просто-напросто бред

Comment: Аккуратней с использованием термина "функтор". В разных языках (программирования) он имеет разное значение. Данное в википедии -- из языка Пролог. Вот определение из другой статьи в этой же педивикии: "Функторы — это отображения категорий, сохраняющие структуру."

Comment: Давать пример лямбда-выражения на PHP это конечно зашибись -- насколько мне известно они там кастрированные.

Comment: @drdaeman, по мне, так create_function имеет значение к лямбда функциям. Такая информация у меня отсюда: 

http://www.php.su/functions/?create_html

Comment: @Asen, к анонимным функциям (как они есть в большинстве других языков) — не имеет. Строго говоря, нормальных анонимных функций в PHP функции **нет** вообще, уже потому что функции в нем не являются объектами первого класса (т.е. в PHP нет типа «функция» и передать функцию нельзя *никак*, кроме как строкой-именем). Максимум, что есть в PHP 5.3+ — это аналог шарповских делегатов. Про `create_function` — лямбды, традиционно, имеют непосредственное отношение к синтаксису языка, а, `create_function`, являясь оберткой над `eval` — никакого. Несмотря на написанное на заборе^W^W в документации по PHP

Comment: Ок, благодарю за пояснения )