# Выбрать все строки из столбца DataTable

Tags: c#, ado.net

Приветствую. У меня на форме есть `DataGridView` заполненный таблицей из БД. Нужно получить все `Name` в отдельный `List<>` но не из `DataGridView` а напрямую из объекта `DataTable`. Такое возможно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод который возвращает DataTable :

```
public DataTable materialsNEW()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string get = "select * from Materials";
            SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand(get, conn);
            DataTable mattable = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comd);
            adapter.Fill(mattable);
            conn.Open();
            table = mattable;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Ну так покажите код заполнения `datagridview` и сразу можно будет дать Вам ответ, так, пока, можно только гадать. Получить список можно, но нужен Ваш код

Comment: А разве это влияет? Код добавил

Comment: не влияет. `var names = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();`

Comment: или `var names = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row["Name"]).ToList();`

Comment: это linq? не могли бы вы пояснить что означает =>? а то я линками вообще не пользовался. к стыду своему даже не особо понимаю для чего они нужны(

Comment: да, это `linq`, по поводу второго вопроса можно прочесть тут: [Что-такое-лямбда-выражения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/111697/Что-такое-лямбда-выражения) или на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/library/bb397687(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: если после прочтения по-прежнему будут вопросы - спрашивайте, попробую помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так должно быть:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    names.Add(row["Name"].ToString());
```

После того, как заполните свой `DataTable table` - напишите этот код и получите что нужно.

Comment: Ах, молодец - на 20 секунд раньше.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
List<string> names = new List<string>();
foreach(DataRow row in mattable.Rows)
  names.Add(System.Convert.ToString(row["Name"]));
```