# Что такое лямбда в понятии Android Studio и стоит ли идти у нее на поводу?

Tags: android, android-studio, lambda

На днях обновил Android Studio до финальной версии 3.4. Было замечено много исправлений и улучшений в работе этой среды. Но одним из нововведений было предложение студии отказаться от стандартных выражений и заменить их на лямбда выражения. Вот к примеру клик по кнопке до обновления:

```
 backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

и после обновления:

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(view -> dialog.dismiss());
```

Как говорится в одном из ответов по поводу лямбда выражений:

> Лямбда-функции - это функции, у которой фактически нет имени.

вот этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/111697/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). То есть у того же самого обработчика после обновления студии резко пропало имя?? Я допускаю что это все происходит из-за перехода на новую Java, но я не уверенн. Как реагировать на предложения студии изменить код? В чем плюсы и минусы использования этих выражений - может устройству легче обрабатывать команды или интерпритировать их? В чем вообще суть этого нововведения?

Comment: Такое уже года 2-3 есть. Возможно просто в новой версии это добавили без необходимости явно указывать 8 версию Явы. По сути лямбды - просто синтаксический сахар. Под капотом остаются те же анонимные классы. Стоит ли использовать? Да, все так делают, ибо кода меньше и его проще читать для простых случаев, типа приведённого вами.

Comment: конкретно у обработчика, который вам предложили заменить на лямду, имени и не было - это анонимный класс, не знаю, почему вы думаете, что оно "резко пропало" (под именем тут понимается ссылка на экземпляр класса, по которой к нему можно обратиться, как `v`  здесь `View v = new View()` ). В данном случае лямбда - укороченная запись анонимного класса (1 команда заменяют 3 строки). Использовать это или нет - дело ваше/Ответы  по лямбда функциям в контексте Java вы выбрали немного не подходящие. Лучше искать для именно Java. И лямбды это не в понятиях студии - это из Java 8 нововведение